# batch file to merge .js files from subfolders into one combined file

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, merge, subdirectory

I'm struggling to get this to work.  Plenty of examples on the web, but they all do something just slightly different to what I'm aiming to do, and every time I think I can solve it, I get hit by an error that means nothing to me.

After giving up on the JSLint.VS plugin, I'm attempting to create a batch file that I can call from a Visual Studio build event, or perhaps from cruise control, which will generate JSLint warnings for a project.  The final goal is to get a combined js file that I can pass to jslint, using:

```
cscript jslint.js < tmp.js
```

which would validate that my scripts are ready to be combined into one file for use in a js minifier, or output a bunch of errors using standard output.

but the js files that would make up tmp.js are likely to be in multiple subfolders in the project, e.g:

```
D:\_projects\trunk\web\projectname\js\somefile.debug.js
D:\_projects\trunk\web\projectname\js\jquery\plugins\jquery.plugin.js
```

The ideal solution would be to be able to call a batch file along the lines of:

```
jslint.bat %ProjectPath%
```

and this would then combine all the js files within the project into one temp js file.  This way I would have flexibility in which project was being passed to the batch file.

I've been trying to make this work with copy, xcopy, type, and echo, and using a for do loop, with dir /s etc, to make it do what I want, but whatever I try I get an error.

Comment: It would be good to post the error too.

Comment: I've had too many to mention.  I've spent a good few hours on it and each time I've hit a brick wall.  I'm not sure which error would have been the closest to the final solution, so I'd have to list about 3 or 4 different attempts and the errors associated with them.

But, if need be, I will re-trace my attempts and list each error I had while doing it :)

Comment: That would be a great idea. Show us the current code you have and the error you getting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a batch file with the following contents:

```
@echo off
pushd "%~1"
for /r %%x in (*.js) do (
    type "%%~x"
)
popd
```

and then run it via:

```
jslint.bat PATH > tmp.js
```

If you don't want to use redirection, you can try:

```
@echo off
pushd "%~1"
echo.>tmp.js
for /r %%x in (*.js) do (
    copy tmp.js + "%%~x" tmp.js > NUL
)
popd
```

note that for simplicity, I haven't bothered doing any error-checking (e.g. checking whether an argument is supplied (although if one isn't, it'll just use the current directory), testing that `tmp.js` doesn't already exist, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

A great place for tips on batch files is [DosTips.com](http://www.dostips.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://nefariousdesigns.co.uk/archive/2010/02/website-builds-using-make/

The post is written for Linux world but still you might be able to salvage something out of it.